# Mysql "The installation failed, the installer encountered and error that caused the installation to fail"

Tags: mysql

I have problems to reinstall MySQL on Mac OS X after it was running on my system.

I uninstalled it because the PreferencePane wasn't working as expected, using the procedure described here: http://akrabat.com/computing/uninstalling-mysql-on-mac-os-x-leopard/

When trying to reinstall MySQL Mac OS X ver. 10.6 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive version using the PKG-installer, it says `The installation failed`

Here are the complete logs of the installation:

I will really appreciate any help

```
Sep  7 15:12:10 Mariana.local installd[18515]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/MySQLStartupItem.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root/Library/StartupItems, uid=0)
Sep  7 15:12:10 Mariana.local installd[18515]: PackageKit: prevent user idle system sleep
Sep  7 15:12:10 Mariana.local installd[18515]: PackageKit: suspending backupd
Sep  7 15:12:10 Mariana.local installd[18515]: PackageKit: Shoving /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root (1 items) to /
Sep  7 15:12:10 Mariana.local install_monitor[18520]: Temporarily excluding: /Applications, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Sep  7 15:12:10 Mariana.local installd[18515]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postinstall" in /Volumes/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/MySQLStartupItem.pkg/Contents/Resources
Sep  7 15:12:10 Mariana.local install_monitor[18520]: Re-included: /Applications, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Sep  7 15:12:11 Mariana.local installd[18515]: PackageKit: releasing backupd
Sep  7 15:12:11 Mariana.local installd[18515]: PackageKit: allow user idle system sleep
Sep  7 15:12:11 Mariana.local installd[18515]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “MySQLStartupItem.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7fb809c201f0 {NSFilePath=./postinstall, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/MySQLStartupItem.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.mysql.mysqlstartup, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “MySQLStartupItem.pkg”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./postinstall";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cMySQLStartupItem.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/MySQLStartupItem.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.mysql.mysqlstartup";
    }
Sep  7 15:12:11 Mariana.local Installer[18449]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “MySQLStartupItem.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7f82d14a84c0 {NSFilePath=./postinstall, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/MySQLStartupItem.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.mysql.mysqlstartup, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “MySQLStartupItem.pkg”.}
Sep  7 15:12:11 Mariana.local Installer[18449]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Sep  7 15:12:11 Mariana.local Installer[18449]: IFDInstallController D0434500 state = 7
Sep  7 15:12:11 Mariana.local Installer[18449]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Sep  7 15:12:11 Mariana.local Installer[18449]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```